# Qt no such file or directory 'atomic' on linux bullseye

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi

Im having problem when i build a fresh project , nothing was added/ remove; i get an error `no such file or directory 'atomic'`

[image]

So i investigate a bit and i kind of found the culprit on the makefile. on line 43

```
line 43: LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) /opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l/lib/libQt6Quick.so /opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l/lib/libQt6OpenGL.so /opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l/lib/libQt6Gui.so -lEGL /opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l/lib/libQt6QmlModels.so /opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l/lib/libQt6Qml.so -pthread /opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l/lib/libQt6Network.so /opt/Qt/6.2.3-armv7l/lib/libQt6Core.so -latomic -lpthread -lGLESv2 atomic
```

removing word "atomic" at the end removes the error but im not sure if this is the right thing to do as it might cause some weird bugs under the hood. Qt says the line causing the error is line 228

```
line 227: untitled:  $(OBJECTS)  
line 228:   $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)
```

How do i properly solve this issue?

I am using qt 6.2

Since this is a fresh unmodified project the .pro is also at default

```
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Please add your Qt version and the contents of `.pro` file in your question.

Comment: @Azeem apologies, i have now included them

Comment: Thanks! Is there an `#include` directive in `main.cpp`? What you observed looks like an issue as there are two flags i.e. `-latomic` and `atomic`. The last one `atomic` without `-l` looks redundant.

Comment: Could you also include your operating system?

Comment: @Azeem There is but only the default from the template, `#include <QGuiApplication>`  and `#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>`

Comment: @m7913d Im running on the official 32bit raspberry pi OS bullseye (linux)

Comment: can you add this project to one Github repo and add its link in question? I want to test it, I think your creation of the project has a problem if it doesn't we will be sure that it relates to your installation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are building Qt6 on a Raspberry PI, which isn't an official supported platform.

**Does removing `atomic` may result in some weird bugs?**

No, that shouldn't be the case. A missing needed libraries would result in a link time error, not a runtime error.

Off course, since Raspberry PI isn't a supported platform, weird things may happen because it is not (well) tested on this platform, but this will not be related to removing the `atomic` library.

It seems to me a bug in the Makefile generation code, as library are normally specified using the `-l` option (which searches for the lib in the specified library search path), instead of providing the relative path to the library. As pointed out in the comments `-latomic` is also specified. So, `atomic` seems to be unneeded.

**Why does Qt report the error at line 228?**

Because this is the line that generates the full linker statement that is being executed. Line 43 is included by `$(LIBS)`.

**Tracking the root cause**

Searching for `atomic` inside your (modified) source code of Qt may point you why this library is added to the `LIBS` variable. The best solution is to remove it at that place.

**Relevant resources**

Note that this issue is already discussed [here](https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-62-raspberry-pi).

Comment: I did use that EXACT guide to install qt6.2. qt has a linux installer for 64bit, i wonder if i switch to 64 bit and use the offical installer that would work

Comment: But which guide did you use? I'm not familiar with Raspberry PI, but it seems to me that this isn't supported by the official Qt (installer).